# Error trying to Install Windows Build tools

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, npm, discord.js

When I run `npm run windows-intall` aka

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools && npm install --production
```

I get the following error. I've got python 3.8.2 installed, Node v14.0.0 x64 installed, Powershell added to path [in environment variables, User variables/System Variables, PATH]. Windows Build tools downloaded from VScommunity. I downloaded Windows dev too the universal option.(Haven't restarted PC yet)

Here is the error I got:

> ```
> node ./dist/index.js
>
> Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
> [>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
> Downloaded python-2.7.15.amd64.msi. Saved to C:\Users\tariq\.windows-build-tools\python- 
> 2.7.15.amd64.msi.
> Downloading vs_BuildTools.exe
> [>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
> Downloaded vs_BuildTools.exe. Saved to C:\Users\tariq\.windows-build-tools\vs_BuildTools.exe.
>
> Starting installation...
> events.js:292
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: spawn powershell.exe ENOENT
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
> at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
> Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
> at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
>   errno: -4058,
>   code: 'ENOENT',
>   syscall: 'spawn powershell.exe',
>   path: 'powershell.exe',
>   spawnargs: [
>     '-ExecutionPolicy',
>     'Bypass',
>     '-NoProfile',
>     '-NoLogo',
>     "& {& 'C:\\Users\\tariq\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\windows-build-tools\\ps1\\launch-installer.ps1' -BuildToolsInstallerPath 'C:\\Users\\tariq\\.windows-build-tools' -InstallBuildTools -ExtraBuildToolsParameters '' -PythonInstaller 'python-2.7.15.amd64.msi' -InstallPython -VisualStudioVersion '2017' }"
>   ]
> }
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall: `node ./dist/index.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\tariq\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-05T04_48_32_980Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! gawesomebot@5.0.0 windows-install: `npm install -g --production windows-build-tools && npm install --production`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the gawesomebot@5.0.0 windows-install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\tariq\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-05T04_48_33_077Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `command-line` as **administrator** and try this:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0
```