# Installing --global windows-build-tools never completes

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install --global windows-build-tools by running below command

`npm install --global windows-build-tools -verbose`

No matter if I try through PowerShell or CMD (both as Administrator), the installation gets stuck in the same step.

`npm info run windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall node_modules/windows-build-tools node ./dist/index.js`
`[##################] | reify:resolve: info run windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall node_modules/windows-build-tools node ./dist/index.js`

Is there a reason why this might not complete?

Comment: How long are you giving it? Sometimes reify steps can take a while...

Comment: I waited for more than 2 hours. I would be super surprised if that takes longer! :D

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely broken... Have you tried removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and running a fresh `npm install`?

Comment: `windows-build-tools` is also deprecated, so it's totally possible that 1) it's not compatible with your version of node and 2) you don't need it. See here: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools

Answer (score 22):

**According to the [windows-build-tools repo](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools)**

> Please note that the official Node.js for Windows installer can now
> automatically install the required tools. That's likely a much better
> option than the module listed here (windows-build-tools).

**recommended approach:**

1. Go to [node-download-page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. Download LTS version for windows
3. Follow the installation instructions
4. When you got to this window, check the checkbox
   [image]
5. After the installation it will prompt you to this window, it will automatically download the necessary dependencies
   [image: gyp-installation]

If you want to use this package(**not recommended**):

You should try to roll back to version 4.0.0

Run the `command-line` as **administrator** and try this:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0
```

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208689/error-trying-to-install-windows-build-tools/66678945#66678945)

Comment: @Yedida Rashi, I'm using NVM to install manage different versions of nodejs. Do you have any idea how LTS version can be installed?

Comment: Hey i hope this will help https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/discussions/627#discussioncomment-426255

Answer (score 5):

If you're having trouble installing `windows-build-tools` (which I had a problem with recently), you should roll back to version *4.0.0*.

Run PowerShell as Administrator, and then type in the following command (assuming you have `node` and `npm` installed).

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0
```

This process can take some time, so please be patient.

### Built-in Node.js Build Tools

There are built-in Node.js build tools, so it is recommended to use this. In fact, if you go on the npm or GitHub page of the `windows-build-tools` package, it will say that you should use the Node.js build tools.

To do this, go to [the official Node.js download website](https://nodejs.org/), and download the LTS version. Then, run the installer. At a point in the installation, it will have a checkbox that says *Automatically install the recommended tools*. Make sure to check that!

When you install it, it will also install Chocolatey, and install the build tools like the `windows-build-tools` package.

---

Even though both of these work, **it is recommended to use the Node.js built tools**!

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Due to the Python error, as a result of my research on the internet, I learned that installing `npm install --global windows-build-tools` would solve my problem. However, when I was installing the package, I was using version 16 of NodeJS and I kept getting errors or it was interrupted.

I continued to get errors when I installed `npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0`, but when I used NodeJS 14, I installed the package without any problems.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Following this thread for a while now.

Disclaimer: Please note that I know this is not directly answering your question about why the process gets stuck but I want to share my solution anyway.

The installation via chocolatey did not work for me, as mentioned in:

- https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/245
- https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/152

Then, I found this [microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/365971/unable-to-install-visual-c-build-tools.html). On this page, the person asked this question:

> I tried to install the Microsoft Visual C++ Build tools. The installer
> (filename is visualcppbuildtools_full.exe) stops right after the start
> of the installation it says a setup package is missing or damaged("Ein
> Setuppaket fehlt oder ist beschädigt"). The option to download it
> again doesnt work. Downloading the installer again doesnt help. Trying
> to do an offline installation doesnt work either and I get the same
> error. How can I find out what exactly the problem is and how can I
> solve it?

The solution mentions the page https://my.visualstudio.com/Download that provides different build tool versions:

[image]

I was able to download and install "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9)".

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to install the latest version, but version 4.0.0 is acceptable, this is how
Installing 4.0.0 version managed to complete here, but it took several minutes.

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0                                                    ❮  14s 643ms    255
    npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    npm WARN deprecated windows-build-tools@4.0.0: Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.
    
    added 103 packages, and audited 105 packages in 1m
    
    5 moderate severity vulnerabilities
    
    Some issues need review, and may require choosing
    a different dependency.
    
    Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, what helped me was to uninstall:

1. node.js
2. all versions of VS tools
3. remove chocolatey and window-build-tools npm package
4. all python versions

Then install node.js with checked option to install the tools. And finally it finished.